# Accessing next sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML snippet like below :

```
<tr><td></br></td></tr>
<tr title="title"><td></td><td>凝固検査専用容器</td></tr>
<tr id='map_6011' />
<tr id='map_6012' />
<tr id='map_6010' />
<tr id='map_6184' />
<tr id='map_6336' />    
<tr><td></br></td></tr>

<tr title="title"><td></td><td>血糖専用容器(NaF入り)</td></tr>
<tr id='map_2055' />
<tr id='map_3471' />    
<tr><td></br></td></tr>

<tr title="title"><td></td><td>ｱﾝﾓﾆｱ専用容器</td></tr>
<tr id='map_2142' />
```

First I want to select each TR tag with the title "title", and then first sibling of that particular TR tag.(ie, next TR with an ID like 'map_xxxx').

I have my javascript like this :

```
var lblTRs=$("tr[title=title]");
for(var i=0;i<lblTRs.length;i++){
    var obj=lblTRs[i];
    var firstTRSibling=obj.nextSibling;
    alert(firstTRSibling); //this gives [object Text]
}
```

But  it doesn't give the actual TR sibling.The alert() gives [object Text].

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: why don't you use obj.next();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var firstTRSibling;
while((firstTRSibling=obj.nextSibling).nodeType !== 3){
                                               //   ^-----indicates TEXT_NODE
    obj=obj.nextSibling;
}
alert(firstTRSibling);
```

You have extra white-space characters between DOM elements, and they will be treated as text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$("tr[title='title']").each(function() {
    var element = $(this).next();
});
```

BTW, `<tr>` should have closing tags (i.e. `</tr>`) and also contain the specified number of `<td></td>` tags inside.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the white space between each pair of `<tr>` elements is represented as a text node in the DOM. However, there are seemingly little-known properties of of table-related elements that make dealing with this quite easy. Specifically in this case, the `rows` property of `<table>` elements and the `rowIndex` property of `<tr>` elements. Assuming you have a `<tr>` element stored in a variable called `tr`, all you need is:

```
tr.parentNode.rows[tr.rowIndex + 1];
```

This works in all major browsers back to IE 4 and is part of the DOM standard. It is also faster and more compatible than using jQuery or another library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I should use

```
var firstTRSibling=obj.nextSibling.nextSibling;
```

But why?_

Comment: If your HTML has white space between the nodes, you will see text nodes as the nextSibling. As @Engineer has answered, you need to check the nodeType to make sure it is an element rather than a text node.

Answer (score 0):

As you're already are using jQuery, i'd recommend to use jQuery built-in [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function.

It could be somthing like `var lblTRs=$("tr[title=title]").next("tr");`